# When flex-direction is set to column does the main axes flow in a vertical direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Just wanted to make sure my conceptual model of flexbox is correct.  When we set `flex-direction` to `column` does the **main axes** flow in a vertical direction?

Comment: I've had the same question for a while. I would like a confirmation of this, too :)

Comment: Last time I checked `vertical = column` and `horizontal = row`

Comment: Your comment is correct, but the terminology is not.  This question is asking what direction the main axis flows in when flex-direction is set to column ...

Comment: The answer to this question is provided in many, many existing posts. I've listed only three as duplicates. Not sure why this question needs to be re-opened.

Comment: So you are saying that this question is about how flex wrap works?

Comment: No. I'm not saying this question is about how flex wrap works. I'm saying that that post has an answer that fully addresses your question.

Comment: Also, notice the part that says: **"This question already has an answer here:"** Duplicates are not really about the question. They're about the answers.

Comment: How does an answer to how flex wrap works address this question?

Comment: If you read the answer you will find out.

Comment: OK - Finally found it after scanning for minutes ... not that different from citing Wikipedia or the specification and saying the answer is there though ... people come to stackoverflow for simple answers to simple questions ....

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://codeburst.io/understanding-basic-concepts-of-css-flexbox-ffa657dc39c1) the **main axis** does flow in a vertical direction when `flex-direction` is set to `column`:

> Remember that once you set the value to column, the main and cross axes are switched up.